# gdb-customize command, how to test whether a variable is set?

Tags: gdb

I'm debuging with gdb and need to define some helper commands. Basically I want my customized command to operate differently depending on the number of args given.

So I have to test whether `$arg*` is given, see the code below:

```
define pgdir

    set $pgdir = $arg0

    if ($arg1) {
        // show the corresponding PDE
    } else {
        // show the whole page directory
    }

end
```

Is it possible to test whether a variable is void?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [convenience function](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Funs.html) `$_isvoid()`. It returns 1 if the variable is void.

```
(gdb) set $v = 1
(gdb) print $_isvoid($v)
$1 = 0
(gdb) print $_isvoid($v2)
$2 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`gdb` supports `$argc` which per the manual expands out to something from 0..10, so in your case it would probably be

```
define pgdir
  if $argc == 2
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks thrig, could you please tell me how I can test a variable is void except the answer I just posted?

Answer (score 0):

As for my problem, there is a `$argc` variable so that I can do this:

```
define pgdir

    set $pgdir = $arg0

    if ($argc == 1) {
        // show the corresponding PDE
    } else {
        // show the whole page directory
    }

end
```

As for the question **how to test whether a variable is void**, I thought of a tricky and inelegant way: **test whether the variable is equal to a variable with void value**.

```
define func

    if ($var_to_test == $var_that_no_one_is_like_to_use_so_that_it_is_void)
        // do something

end
```